# Why am I Not Able to Format my Code Properly?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Whenever I try to ask a question or give an answer, I am unable to insert my code properly. I have tried to put the code in single quotes and to press `Ctrl K`. It works for short code samples, but if I have long code, how can I format it properly?

Comment: You could try formatting your Question Properly As well Because Typing Each word with A Captial is Very Annoying. Check out [this FaQ question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for guide to formatting code.

Comment: Examples?  You get up to [30k characters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88417/is-there-a-limitation-of-total-characters-number-in-description-text-area) for answers and 40k for questions.  If your code is longer (after adding whitespace for the code formatting) than 30,000 characters, then you won't be able to post it.  How long is "Some Long Code"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put the code in single quotes first.  There are backticks (`) that are used to format quote inline with the text.  For example `here`, but these are not to be confused with `'`.

Or you can highlight a block of code and hit Ctrl-K.

```
block
block
block
```